# ELOM/ILOM equivalent in Apple servers

Tags: mac, mac-osx-server

Is there a similar solution for low level server management in firmware for hardware like Mac Mini Server? If no, what is the best way to ensure remote management even with serious issues like not booting OS?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Apple had an IPMI implementation (or a subset of it) in their XServes, but since those were discontinued, there is no kind of LOM left in any of Apple's offering. The MacMini server (or the MacPro) are *no* servers, they just ship with the Lion Server variant preinstalled.

If you need stuff like that, look elsewhere, Apple isn't offering anything.

Answer (score 2):

No, there's no solution from Apple for out-of-band management. Perhaps an IP KVM is an option in some scenarios, but there's nothing native to the Apple hardware now.